# Pandas concat converts dtype to object instead of numeric

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset separated into 10 different .csv files. After importing each separately, I use concat to merge them into one. This converts each column to dtype "object". As a result, when I use Keras model .fit to run the model, I get the error: ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).

Running the exact same code to one .csv file, meaning without concating, works fine.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("CSE-CIC-IDS2018/02-14-2018.csv", low_memory=False, nrows=10000)
df2 = pd.read_csv("CSE-CIC-IDS2018/02-15-2018.csv", low_memory=False, nrows=10000)
df3 = pd.read_csv("CSE-CIC-IDS2018/02-16-2018.csv", low_memory=False, nrows=10000)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
df.drop(columns=['Timestamp','Flow ID', 'Src IP', 'Src Port', 'Dst IP'], inplace=True)

df.head()

Dst Port    Protocol    Flow Duration   Tot Fwd Pkts    Tot Bwd Pkts    TotLen Fwd Pkts TotLen Bwd Pkts Fwd Pkt Len Max Fwd Pkt Len Min Fwd Pkt Len Mean    ... Fwd Seg Size Min    Active Mean Active Std  Active Max  Active Min  Idle Mean   Idle Std    Idle Max    Idle Min    Label
0   0   0   112641719   3   0   0   0   0   0   0.0 ... 0   0   0   0   0   56320859.5  139.300036  56320958    56320761    Benign
1   0   0   112641466   3   0   0   0   0   0   0.0 ... 0   0   0   0   0   56320733.0  114.551299  56320814    56320652    Benign
2   0   0   112638623   3   0   0   0   0   0   0.0 ... 0   0   0   0   0   56319311.5  301.934596  56319525    56319098    Benign
    3   22  6   6453966 15  10  1239    2273    744 0   82.6    ... 32  0   0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   0   Benign
    4   22  6   8804066 14  11  1143    2209    744 0   81.642857   ... 32  0   0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0   0   Benign

x = df.drop(["Label", axis=1)
y = df["Label"].apply(lambda x:0 if x=="Benign" else 1)

x_train, x_remaining, y_train, y_remaining = train_test_split(x,y, train_size=0.60, random_state=4)
x_val, x_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(x_remaining, y_remaining, test_size=0.5, random_state=4)

#Model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(16, activation="relu"))#, input_dim=len(x_train.columns)))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"))
    #model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))
    
    #Compiler
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="Adam", metrics="accuracy")
    
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=512)
```

**ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).**

Comment: Show the full error traceback.  Which line of your code is raising it?  Then check the dataframe `dtypes`, working back to the freshly loaded ones if necessary.  Pandas uses object dtype for strings and fill values like None.

Answer (score 0):

One of your columns is not numeric. Use `x.select_dtypes` to show them.

```
# Good case because x does not contain object columns
>>> x.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
Index([], dtype='object')

# Bad case because the list is not empty
>>> x.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
Index(['Protocol'], dtype='object')
```

As you can see, there is a problem with the `Protocol` column because it should be numeric. Now you know the column names, you can debug. Try the code below to show bad rows.

```
>>> x.loc[pd.to_numeric(x['Protocol'], errors='coerce').isna(), 'Protocol']
3    tcp
Name: Protocol, dtype: object
```

For example, you can drop the row 3 and convert the column as integer:

```
x = x.drop(3).astype({'Protocol': int})
```

However to be sure to have unique index and determine bad rows, use `ignore_index=True` as parameter of `pd.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)
```